# CXF/Jetty Rest API Not Working After Eclipse/Java/CXF/Jetty Upgrade

Tags: eclipse, jetty, cxf

We have inherited an Eclipse RCP application which was based on Eclipse 4.8 (photon) and Java 8. We have upgraded it to Eclipse 4.23 and Java 11. During the upgrade we had to update lot of 3rd party dependencies which include CXF from version 3.3.7 to 3.6.1 and Jetty from version 9.4.50 to 10.0.15.

After this update we saw that the REST API written using CXF and hosted using Jetty were no longer working but the SOAP services were still running fine. The REST services are not even starting. There are no logs in the server logs or eclipse logs that points to any error. On some debugging we found that the WebAppContext is not getting started. In previous version we could see few lines in the logs that were initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext and then starting WebAppContext but in the updated eclipse version we do not see any such logs.

The code is old and using web.xml and cfxwsbean.xml files for configuring rather than Java annotations. We are not sure if there is something wrong with the configurations in these files or not as they were working fine in previous versions.

I am not sure below logs are correct or not , because it has some null value

2023-09-15 17:04:22,812 INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@43ac6f25{/test,null,AVAILABLE}{file:/C:/Users/Project/}